# How can I stop <Image Source="file path"/> process?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I stop `<Image Source="file path"/>` process?
I want to stop this proccess because i can't use `File.Delete();`

Comment: Process? What process?

Comment: I think that i can't delete the file because it is opened from Image Control

Comment: What??? Your question sounds like "How do I make a apple out of a banana"

Comment: That's no separate process, but the process handle of your application...

Comment: I have a Bitmap object and object with his path.I want to delete the file from the path,although it show me a error "The file is used be another proccees"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
XAML:

```
<Image Source="file path" x:Name="image"/>
```

C#:

```
image.Source = null; 
System.IO.File.Delete(@"C:\person.gif");
```

Comment: You should `Dispose` of it first, don't you?

Comment: Image have no Dispose method.

Comment: Why yes it does: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is an Image object in System.Drawing. In this case Image is a WPF Control. So they're difference. :D

Comment: :D No need to say sorry, Sir!